# std::optional<T> appears to destroy T twice when leaving its scope. Why?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, stdoptional

I'm looking to replace some old raw pointer handling for objects (unparented QObjects) that in practice are treated as optional objects.
E.g:

```c++
if(m_file)
   delete m_file;
m_file = new QFile(...);`
```

Both std::unique_ptr and std::optional seem to be suitable for my needs.

I decided to do some testing first, and came across some strange behaviour with std::optional: The T::dtor appears to be called twice when exiting scope.

https://godbolt.org/z/Yeq887YPh.

```C++
struct Loud
{
    Loud(std::string name) : m_name{ name } { print("Creating"); }
    Loud(const Loud& other) : m_name{ other.m_name } { print("Copying"); }
    Loud(Loud&& other) : m_name{ other.m_name }{ print("Moving"); }
    ~Loud() { print("Destroying"); }
    Loud& operator=(const Loud& other){ this->m_name = other.m_name; print("Copy="); return *this;}
    Loud& operator=(Loud&& other){ this->m_name = other.m_name; print("Move=");; return *this;}

    std::string m_name;
    void print(std::string operation) { std::cout << operation << " " << m_name << "\n"; }
};

void optionalTest()
{
    std::optional<Loud> opt;
    opt = Loud("opt 1");
    opt = Loud("opt 2");
}

void uniqueTest()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Loud> unique;
    unique = std::make_unique<Loud>("unique 1");
    unique =  std::make_unique<Loud>("unique 2");
}

int main()
{
    optionalTest();
    std::cout << "\n";
    uniqueTest();
}
```

Which produces the output

```
Creating opt 1
Moving opt 1
Destroying opt 1
Creating opt 2
Move= opt 2
Destroying opt 2
Destroying opt 2    <-- Whyy??

Creating unique 1
Creating unique 2
Destroying unique 1
Destroying unique 2
```

I'm a bit worried that the double dtor might cause issues with deallocating resources, so I'm currently more inclined to opt for the unique_ptr.

---

Edit:

Only the last destruction is the actual `std::optional<Loud> opt` object being destroyed. The rest of the destructors are from temporaries.

Its illustrated better by changing the `other.m_name` in the move operators (https://godbolt.org/z/3vWfPPY7b).

Output:

```
Creating opt 1
Moving opt 1
Destroying opt 1 (mvd from)
Creating opt 2
Move= opt 2
Destroying opt 2 (mvd from)
Destroying opt 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine. You have 3 objects being worked on:

a) in `std::optional`,
b) temporary `opt 1` and
c) temporary `opt2`.

Now, referring those to your output:

```
Creating opt 1   // create b
Moving opt 1     // create a using b
Destroying opt 1 // destroy b
Creating opt 2   // create c
Move= opt 2      // update a using c
Destroying opt 2 // destroy c
Destroying opt 2 // destroy a
```

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't store its own object, only a pointer, so there's no 3rd object in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Creating opt 2
Move= opt 2
Destroying opt 2
Destroying opt 2    <-- Whyy??
```

Because you created one `opt 2` object, and then move-assigned it to another one. It says so, right there.

Move assigning (or constructing) does ***not*** destroy the moved-from objects as part of the move. The moved-from object still exists, and your move operation still has both objects tagged as "opt 2". You now have two `opt 2` objects in existence. Each one has to get destroyed, at some point.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense by its own, but when I extend the code with `opt = Loud("opt 3");`, I get the following output:
`.... Creating opt 2, Move= opt 2, Destroying opt 2, Creating opt 3, Move= opt 3, Destroying opt 3,  Destroying opt 3`
I would in this case expect "opt 2" to still be destroyed twice. Once for the temporary, and once when the optional container releases "opt 2" to be assigned "opt 3".

Comment: "once when the optional container releases "opt 2" to be assigned "opt 3." The optional container does not release opt2. It overwrites it with opt3 via the Move= operator. Update your print() method to print the value of "this" to see better what's going on.

Comment: @JensJoberg `std::optional` has overloaded `operator=` to forward the call directly to the held object (avoiding destruction and creation of held object as a result). Basically, with `Loud a, b; std::optional<Loud> opt {a};` ,`a = b;` and `opt = b;` do the same thing.

Comment: I guess that is where my mental model of `optional` was wrong. I've thought of it as something like a `unique_ptr`, but on the stack. Obviously there is more to it than that. I guess its an ok assumption for POD's, but might get a bit more tricky with RAII types.

I would then think its safer to replace the old `if(m_var) delete m_var; m_var = new ...` mess with `unique_ptr` as thats more in line with the old behaviour.

Comment: @JensJoberg Right. The equivalent to an updating `optional` assignment would be something like `*unique = Loud{"unique 2"};`. The `unique` holds the same object, but the object has been assigned from another object.

Answer (score 0):

In the `std::optional` case there are three `Loud` objects in the `std::unique_ptr<Loud>` case there are only two `Loud` objects.

For `std::optional`:

```
void optionalTest()
{
    std::optional<Loud> opt;
    //A std::optional to hold a <Loud> object is created

    opt = Loud("opt 1");
    //An Object <Loud> with "opt 1" is created
    //The Object <Loud> with "opt 1" is move assigned to the <Loud> object in std::optional:
    // => m_name in <Loud> with "opt 1" is still "opt 1"
    // => m_name in <Loud> in the std::optional is now "opt 1"
    //The Object <Loud> with "opt 1" goes out of scope and is destroyed

    opt = Loud("opt 2");
    //An Object <Loud> with "opt 2" is created
    //The Object <Loud> with "opt 2" is move assigned to the <Loud> object in std::optional:
    // => m_name in the <Loud> with "opt 2" is still "opt 2"
    // => m_name in <Loud> in the std::optional is now "opt 2"
    //The Object <Loud> with "opt 2" goes out of scope and is destroyed

    //The std::optional goes out of scope, and gets destroyed alongside its own <Loud> Object, which has a m_name with "opt 2"
}
```

And for `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void uniqueTest()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Loud> unique;
    //A std::unique_ptr to hold a pointer to a <Loud> object is created

    unique = std::make_unique<Loud>("unique 1");
    //An Object <Loud> with "opt 1" is created on the Heap
    //The pointer to the <Loud> with "opt 1" is assigned to the std::unique_ptr
    
    unique = std::make_unique<Loud>("unique 2");
    //An Object <Loud> with "opt 2" is created on the Heap
    //The pointer to the <Loud> with "opt 2" is assigned to the std::unique_ptr
    //The std::unique_ptr automatically deletes the <Loud> with "opt 1"

    //The std::unique_ptr goes out of scope and is destryoed, automatically deleting the <Loud> with "opt 2"
}
```

I think the confusion might come from the fact that the move-assignment operator does not actually move *the object itself*, but rather the contents of the object (or at least it should); or, as the cppreferences puts it

> Move assignment operators typically "steal" the resources held by the argument (e.g. pointers to dynamically-allocated objects, file descriptors, TCP sockets, I/O streams, running threads, etc.), rather than make copies of them, and leave the argument in some valid but otherwise indeterminate state.